# An application hijacked a keyboard shortcut, how can I get it back?

Tags: windows-7, firefox, keyboard-shortcuts

Firefox allows you to reopen closed tabs by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd>, and I use this shortcut a lot. Recently, I installed an application that binds that same shortcut to launch itself, even if Firefox is currently focused.

Unfortunately, I really need this installed application (it's a TV tuner and I haven't found any alternative compatible with my hardware), and it doesn't offer any settings to change this shortcut. I can't uninstall it, but I don't want it to use this shortcut.

How can I recover the original use of that shortcut? If not possible, is there a way to bind a new key combination to Firefox's *Undo close tab* function?

EDIT:Using Windows 7

Answer (score 0):

You need a Firefox plugin called **Keyconfig** - found at http://mozilla.dorando.at/readme.html to reconfigure the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd> shortcut to something else.

Alternatively have a dig about in your TV Tuner help files and see if the shortcut for that app can be changed.